No Data in FAA Methodology Document but Data in Their Emission Calculator
I hope this message finds you well.
While researching carbon emissions for flights from Los Angeles International Airport (LAX) to Tocumen International Airport (PTY), I encountered an interesting discrepancy. Using the FAA's Emission Calculator, I found specific emissions data for the Boeing 737 MAX 9 pax (IATA code: 7M9). However, when consulting the FAA's methodology document for calculating emissions, I noticed that no fuel consumption or related data for this aircraft model is included.
This raises the question: why would the emissions calculator provide data for the Boeing 737 MAX 9 pax while the corresponding methodology document lacks this information? Could it be an oversight, or is there an alternative explanation?
I’m reaching out to this community to seek insights or guidance on this issue. Understanding this inconsistency is crucial for ensuring accurate carbon emissions calculations in my work.
Thank you for your time and input.

Can you link to the calculator you are using?

Thank you for your response! Could you clarify which specific links you’re referring to? Are you asking for the link to the FAA Emission Calculator or the FAA Methodology Document, or both? I’ll be happy to provide them for further context.

It would be good to provide both.
